# Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received. when using redux

Tags: redux, react-redux, store

---

> when using store redux get error in the chrome

---

**Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i disabled my extension chrome like (adblock+adblockplus+...) it working good
or use chrome guest
it work